# Statistical test for proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a gene list with Up=208, Down=135 and No change=44. Total =387.

I have done a random shuffling 1000 times and obtained the mean Up=77.54, Down=74.268 and No change= 235.19

I want to test if the no. of Down-regulated genes are significantly different or Not from the random sampling. Is a test for proportions applicable here ? Any other suggestion ? I would prefer to have stricter conditions because our hypothesis was to show that the proportion is close to the random sampling.

```
In R:
prop.test(135, 387, 0.19, alternative = "two.sided",correct = TRUE, conf.level = 0.99)
```

Kindly suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A test of binomial proportions is fine, provided you have
decided clearly what you want to know. If it's whether there is a difference between 'Up' and 'Down', then you should use
the following:

```
 prop.test(c(208,135), c(343,343), cor=F)

    2-sample test for equality of proportions 
    without continuity correction

data:  c(208, 135) out of c(343, 343)
X-squared = 31.073, df = 1, p-value = 2.485e-08
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1397106 0.2859453
sample estimates:
  prop 1   prop 2 
0.606414 0.393586
```

This makes it clear that $\hat p_u = 0.606$ is very highly statistically
different from $\hat p_d = 0.394.$  As always with a test,
it's a good idea to start by clearly stating null and alternative hypotheses.

*Note:* I have avoided the continuity correction, which I
think is a bad idea unless sample sizes are very small.